# CSV format for a Transport Network

Tags: qgis, csv, network

I am trying to display a network in QGIS. I have network line coordinates in a `.csv` file, stored in 4 columns: `From_X`, `From_Y`, `To_X`, `To_Y`.

I would like to import this file into QGIS but the option `Layer> Add Layer from a Delimited Text File` doesn't allow me to select more than two coordinates: `X` field and `Y` field.

Is there any option that I am missing? I have read some other questions talking about WKT, do I need my data in this format?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the plugin snaileater suggested should work, I think you will have an easier time if you convert your 4 columns to WKT - as you already mentioned in the question - particularly, if there are other columns in the CSV (containing transport link attributes).

Comment: I went for that solution! so my cvs file has a column with LINESTRING((X,Y),(X,Y)) in it.

Answer (score 1):

Points have usually (...) 2 coordinates, what u try to import is obviously **flow map** data with origin/destination information. There are some plugin dedicated to this kind of import ... look for example at **[Oursins plug-in](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Oursins/)** in the repositories, that will help u import that kind of data.

Comment: Thank you @snaileater! I do have the points also, so I could plot the network node locations. As you said, I want to display this flow map. I will have a look at that plug-in

Comment: Look at the plug-in and keep your original data i think the plug-in should do the job (create lines) ...